# indexing timestamptz for specific timezone

Tags: postgresql

My console is PST. 
Database server and times stored are GMT.

I'm having to run queries like so:

```
SELECT x,y,z 
FROM tbl_msg 
WHERE (msg_datetime AT TIME ZONE 'BST') BETWEEN '2016-11-21'::date and '2016-11-22'::date;
```

Indexing 101 says that performing this operation on **msg_datetime** will now avoid the index and this is what I'm seeing.

So I need advice with an indexing solution for this.

Can I index this timezone? or alter this query so that it queries these times in BST, converted to GMT?

Answer (score 0):

You should have `msg_datetime` column of type `timestamp with time zone` (or shorter alias `timestamptz`) with normal index.

Then, to get data for these 2 days, you should:

```
set timezone 'Europe/London'; -- once, on connection start
SELECT x,y,z 
FROM tbl_msg 
WHERE
  msg_datetime>='2016-11-21 00:00:00'
  and
  msg_datetime<'2016-11-23 00:00:00';
```

You should not use ordinary `timestamp`, as it stores literal date and hour without information about which timezone it actually meant. A `timestamp with time zone` type will automatically convert your client's configured time to internal representation (which is in UTC) and back. You can also express timestamptz from non-default timezone using for example `'2016-11-23 00:00:00 Asia/Tokyo'`.

Also you should not use `BST` - because you'd need to use `GMT` on winter and remember when to use which. You should use 'Europe/London' or other "city" timezones ([list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)), which are right both in summer and in winter.

Comment: That's interesting setting the timezone on connection. I've only seen the casting "AT TIME ZONE 'XXX'".

This might be the answer that allows me to pass in a time as BST and have it converted to GMT/UTC rather than having to cast GMT/UTC to BST.

Comment: I see you mention not using BST. That's the whole reason I have to cast like this. The users are BST and want to use BST terms to search in the application. 

That's why I'm casting the data as a different timezone, because we need to allow a timezone aware conversion take place, so it takes that hour into account if need be

Comment: You're wrong - you have no BST users. You might have "Europe/London" users, which use BST timezone (UTC+1) for half a year (as in not today, as it's winter in northern hemisphere), and GMT timezone for another half a year (like today). You might have for example "Europe/Warsaw" clients which use CEST (UTC+2) on summer and CET on winter (which is also UTC+1).